# How to implement custom AWSCredentialsProvider?

Tags: android, aws-sdk

I need to replace `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` with custom `AWSCredentialsProvider`, to add custom headers with every IoT request, is this possible and how?

My current code snippet:

```java
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
AWSIotDataClient iotDataClient = new AWSIotDataClient(credentialsProvider);                iotDataClient.setEndpoint(AWSConstants.CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);
    GetThingShadowRequest request = new GetThingShadowRequest()
                    .withThingName(AWSConstants.TEMP_THING_NAME);
                    GetThingShadowResult result = iotDataClient.getThingShadow(request);
```

Now what I want to do is to replace `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` with custom `CredentialsProvider` to add custom headers with every iot request.

Comment: There is no code or attempt shown in your question, making it difficult to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for your comment , i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Team just contacted aws support and the above question is not applicable.

Edit: aws team is working on that right now, feature will be available soon